# Miracles from Lord Buddha vs messages from Gods?

Tags: the-buddha, buddhist-miracles

I live in Sri Lanka and many good Buddhist ceremonies take place all year long. And more often than not in almost all of these major functions something extraordinary happens that leave the whole country speechless. These events take place not once or twice but annually as these big functions happen every year.

None of these events happen in broad daylight and no one has been able to explain how they occur and that includes all the well renowned Professors and other science related organizations and universities.

These events have broken the once accepted idea that they are some kind of weather or other anomaly as they have happened annually in perfectly equal circumstances that includes a major Buddhist event,a whopping number of pilgrims,a very pleasant environment & etc.The Somawathi Stupa is a fine example....

The best part is none of these events took place when this place is vacant, all of this happened when it was full of Buddhists and everyone there (at least few thousand people every time) witness the events.

---

Here is one event on video in broad daylight...

[**Rays of lights on Somawathi Stupa**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLdqwItKHC8)

Images of the event taken in few different days and angles...

[image: Images of the event]

---

A 3D Hologram like image of Lord Buddha appeared in front of this stupa recently...

[image: 3D Hologram]

---

According to this description on the banner this is supposedly a image of a group of Devas visiting the Stupa...

### [image]

As there has been no proper explanation to these events what so ever people have came to the conclusion that this is the power of Lord Buddha, There is another idea. Some think it's the Devas trying to encourage the people to do good more.

---

**Is there any explanation that you can find?**

**Has such events happened in recent history in any other Buddhist countries,monasteries or events?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of business with it, especially in Asian countries and people love to share each other such stuff on facebook. Yes 1000 of such events :-) They would just not see if an Arahat would cross their ways, or not even look deeply in the Miracle of Dhamma by practicing it.

Attached to form, sound, smell, taste, bodily sensations not to speak of intellect, its had to see.

Once you meet Devas, that you do not need to seek for such on Facebook. Some inspirations:

> [Knowledge](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/thai/lee/knowledge_en.html#shades)
>
> This is called manomayiddhi. When the mind is firmly established, you
>   can go see these things. Or you can go to the land of the nagas, the
>   different lands on the human level — sometimes, when you get tired of
>   human beings, you can go visit the heavens: the heaven of the Four
>   Great Kings, the heaven of the Guardians of the Hours, the
>   Thirty-three gods, all the way up there to the Brahma worlds. The mind
>   can go without any problem. This is called manomayiddhi. It's a lot of
>   fun. Your defilements are gone, your work is done, you've got enough
>   rice to eat and money to spend, so you can go traveling to see the
>   sights and soak up the breezes. That's manomayiddhi.

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Comment: Your answer is very true bhante, but these aren't events shared on facebook. a lot off people witnessed these events,most often thousands. I asked this question seeking an explanation. But what you say is completely true. These events gave a sudden rise to Buddhism and to the path as it was taken as an example to show the power of Buddhism. And actually this brought a lot of people who were lost back in to the path and now we hear a lot of stories from monks about lights visiting temples all over the island. Maybe it was a trick from Devas maybe not, but whatever that was it worked...

Comment: Now we often hear stories from temples and monks about Upasakas dying moments. A lot of good Upasakas are visited by higher realms in last moments. All of these events raised the bar and now we have a good uprising among Buddhists and soon we will have a daily telecasting Buddhist channel on free band television completely funded by Upasakas. Can you take the time to explain the events that i mentioned above? It would be nice to have a explanation from a great one like you. @samana johann

Comment: rupa and when it touches vedana... sanna... sankhara... Its not important. If it gives rise to certain faith that there is more as we perceive what could be perceived end even that is anicca, that its great. Upasaka Thereavada.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal view, I have come to see 'signs' as another form of conditionality. I recall last year while meditating I saw a beautiful 3 dimensional white elephant with the Buddha sat on the top. My sangha said it was a very auspicious sign and I was encouraged to look into it further, purchase an ornament, worship that ornament and so on and so so forth. Instead, I killed it and continued with practice which perplexed some of my sangha.

No matter how wonderful or enigmatic things may appear they are still name and form and thus conditioned and further, impersonal.

Here is a conversation in which Sariputra's qualities of wisdom are compared to the qualities of Venerable Anurudd who is able to travel through the wondrous cosmic planes. Sariputra imparts his wisdom upon Venerable Anuruddha in such a way as to detach Venerable Anuruddha from his Siddhi abilities and focus solely on attaining nibbana.

> Then Venerable Anuruddha went up to Venerable Sāriputta, and exchanged greetings with him. When the greetings and polite conversation were over, he sat down to one side and said to him: “Here’s the thing, Reverend Sāriputta. With clairvoyance that is purified and surpasses the human, I survey the entire galaxy. My energy is roused up and unflagging, my mindfulness is established and lucid, my body is tranquil and undisturbed, and my mind is immersed in samādhi. But my mind is not freed from the defilements by not grasping.”
>
> “Well, Reverend Anuruddha, when you say: ‘With clairvoyance that is
>   purified and surpasses the human, I survey the entire galaxy,’ that’s
>   your conceit. And when you say: ‘My energy is roused up and
>   unflagging, my mindfulness is established and lucid, my body is
>   tranquil and undisturbed, and my mind is immersed in samādhi,’ that’s
>   your restlessness. And when you say: ‘But my mind is not freed from
>   the defilements by not grasping,’ that’s your remorse. It’d be good to
>   give up these three things. Instead of focusing on them, apply your
>   mind to the deathless.”
>
> After some time Anuruddha gave up these three things. Instead of
>   focusing on them, he applied his mind to the deathless. Then
>   Anuruddha, living alone, withdrawn, diligent, keen, and resolute, soon
>   realized the supreme culmination of the spiritual path in this very
>   life. He lived having achieved with his own insight the goal for which
>   people from good families rightly go forth from the lay life to
>   homelessness. He understood: “Rebirth is ended; the spiritual journey
>   has been completed; what had to be done has been done; there is no
>   return to any state of existence.” And Venerable Anuruddha became one
>   of the perfected.

[13. kusināra - 130. Anuruddha (2nd)](https://suttacentral.net/an3.130/en/sujato)